# bind_param what causing the error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($conn->connect_error) {
  $this->last_error = 'Cannot connect to database. ' . $conn->connect_error;
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($conn, DB_NAME);
    if (!$db_select){
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
};

$query = $conn->prepare(
"INSERT INTO user (ID, Name, Gender, Email, Age, Text, Score) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
);

$query->bind_param('sssssi', $name,$gender,$email,$age,$text,$score);
$query->execute();
$query->close();
```

I having this error:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

but when I switch to other computer and use it, I get no error.

Comment: You should probably check whether `$conn->prepare` generates an error instead of assuming that it works.

Comment: You should check if `prepare()` returns an object or false. Try `if(($query = $con->prepare(...)) === FALSE) { die($con->error); }`

Comment: try using var_dump($query) before $query->bind_param

Answer (score 0):

You should make this for catching error messages:

```
if(!($query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (ID, Name, Gender, Email, Age, Text, Score) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")))
    die($conn->error);

if(!$query->bind_param('sssssi', $name,$gender,$email,$age,$text,$score))
    die($conn->error);

$query->execute();
$query->close();
```

Please see the output if there is any for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query is probably `false` and since false is not an object, you are getting the error
```

Use `var_dump($query);` right after your `prepare` call and check whether you are getting any kind of object.

**ALSO**, if the sql query if wrongly constructed and sent to server, `prepare()` will return `false`

**NOTE:** This is what the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) says

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error
>   occurred.

Comment: OP is using `mysqli_`, not PDO